# Implement Multi Long press Android

Tags: android, gesture

I would like to implement a two finger long press in Android.
I tried to override onLongPress:

```
private static final int LONGTIMEOUT = ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout() + 100;

@Override public void onLongPress(final MotionEvent e) {
  Log.i(TAG, "onLongPress");
  switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      Log.i(TAG, "onLongPress:ACTION_DOWN");
      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
      Log.i(TAG, "onLongPress:ACTION_POINTER_DOWN");
      if (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - e.getEventTime() > LONGTIMEOUT)
        Log.i(TAG, "YES YES YES");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

but it never enters ACTION_POINTER_DOWN as I long press with two fingers on the screen.
Does someone have an idea how to solve/implement it correctly?

Comment: Do you use a GestureDetector ? I think GestureDetector does not work with more a one fingers. I'm using that and I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract void onLongPress (MotionEvent e)
```

Definition of `e`according to the android doc:

> The **initial** on down motion event that started the longpress.

This means that if u start a `LongPress` gesture with one finger this finger will be the only one considered by `onLongPress`. I'm not very good with gesture but i think you should first determinate if it is a 2 or 1 finger touch and then see if it's a long press or a normal tap